# open ost backup and search

Tags: gratis, backup, outlook

I backed up my Outlook mail to an ost file. I'm looking for a freeware tool that will allow me to open the .ost file and search the emails.
I tried already "Free Outlook OST File viewer" and "Free ost reader". Both tools don't allow searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Free Outlook Viewer to open Outlook PST and OST files that allow you search in contact &...

http://www.ostpstviewer.com/i/message-view-outlook-pst-file.png

http://www.ostpstviewer.com/free-outlook-viewer-open-pst.aspx